# how to use window.open onClick - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `window.open` but I got this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string
```

---

my code:

```
<img id='drftrgvlnbpewmcswmcs' style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick='window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup","toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30")' alt='' src='http://trustseal.enamad.ir/logo.aspx?id=15288&p=lznbfujyqesgukaqukaq'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put plan string in onClick prop. You have to pass a function.

### Example

```
<img id='drftrgvlnbpewmcswmcs' style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={() => window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup","toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30")} alt='' src='http://trustseal.enamad.ir/logo.aspx?id=15288&p=lznbfujyqesgukaqukaq'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

As it says `Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string`

It should be a function. So you can do the followings

```
openMyWindow = () => {
 window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup","toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30")
}
```

and use it like

```
<img id='drftrgvlnbpewmcswmcs' style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={this.openMyWindow} alt='' src='http://trustseal.enamad.ir/logo.aspx?id=15288&p=lznbfujyqesgukaqukaq'/>
```

or of course this way as mentioned in other answers

```
onClick={() => {
    window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup", "toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30")
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope the code can be usefull for you

```
 <img
      id='drftrgvlnbpewmcswmcs' 
      style={{cursor:'pointer'}} 
      onClick={()=>{ window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup","toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30") }} 
      alt=''
      src='http://trustseal.enamad.ir/logo.aspx?id=15288&p=lznbfujyqesgukaqukaq'
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your code with a function. For example:

```
<img
  id='drftrgvlnbpewmcswmcs'
  style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
  onClick={() => {
    window.open("http://trustseal.enamad.ir/Verify.aspx?id=15288&p=nbpdyncrwkynaqgwaqgw", "Popup", "toolbar=no, location=no, statusbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, width=580, height=600, top=30")
  }}
  alt=''
  src='http://trustseal.enamad.ir/logo.aspx?id=15288&p=lznbfujyqesgukaqukaq'
/>
```